# Regex for allowing words which have only first letter as uppercase?

Tags: javascript, regex, jsp, servlets

I am trying to make a regex which will validate if all the words have their first letter as upper case. ex
like **Fruits** is allowed but **fruits** is not allowed.
also **United States** is allowed but **United states** is not allowed.

also, i don't want to allow only spaces and dots.

i have created the regex for not allowing only space and dots separately but i want them to be in one regex with the upper requirement is their any way to achieve this ??

I'll add what i have tried so far.

please, any help is appreciated.

```
    $.validator.addMethod("first_letter", function(value,element)
    {
        return this.optional(element) || ^[A-Z].*i.test(value);  // 1.) this is what i am trying to check if first letter of every word is uppercase or not  and can this be combined with the 2.) validation i.e "characters" 
    }, "First Letter Should be Capital !!");

    $.validator.addMethod("characters", function(value,element)
    {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z.*\s]*$/i.test(value);  // 2.) For only Allowing Alphabets
    }, "Only Characters are Allowed !!");
    
    $.validator.addMethod("dot", function(value,element)
    {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[^.]*$/i.test(value);  // 3.) For Not Allowing Dot Characters
    }, "Dot chatarcters are not Allowed !!");
    
    $.validator.addMethod("only_space", function(value,element)
    {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[.*\S.*]/i.test(value); // 4.) For Not Allowing Only Spaces
    }, "Only Spaces are not Allowed !!");
```

All the validations

```
    $.validator.addMethod("characters", function(value,element)
    {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z.*\s]*$/i.test(value);
    }, "Only Characters are Allowed !!");
    
    $.validator.addMethod("dot", function(value,element)
    {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[^.]*$/i.test(value);
    }, "Dot chatarcters are not Allowed !!");
    
    $.validator.addMethod("only_space", function(value,element)
    {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[.*\S.*]/i.test(value);
    }, "Only Spaces are not Allowed !!"); 

    $.validator.addMethod("first_letter", function(value,element)
    {
        return this.optional(element) || ^[A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*$/ i.test(value);
    }, "First Letter Should be Capital !!");    // your answer , if i am using it as it is then also its not working and other validations above it are also not working.

$.validator.addMethod("characters", function(value,element)
    {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Z][a-zA-Z.*\s] (?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*$/i.test(value);
    }, "Only Characters are Allowed !!");    // what i tried 

$.validator.addMethod("first_letter", function(value,element)
    {
        return this.optional(element) || /^([A-Z] [a-z] * (([A-Za-z]\s)?[a-z]*)*)(\s+\S+\s*)*$/i.test(value);
    }, "First Letter Should be Capital !!");    // I also tried like this.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern like that can look like:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z][a-z]*` Match a single uppercase char and optional lowercase chars
- `(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*` Optionally repeat matching a space and the same as the previous
- `$` End of string

This pattern is limiter to characters A-Z as the first characters and followed by lowercase characters where there can be a mere space in between the "words".

See a demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gGNwUK/1).

```js
const regex = /^[A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*$/;
[
  "Fruits",
  "fruits",
  "United States",
  "United states"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`));
```

A broader match could be starting with an uppercase char, followed by optional non whitespace characters (that can also again match uppercase characters).

In the repeating part you can use `\s+` to match 1 or more whitespace characters (that can also match a newline).

```
^[A-Z]\S*(?:\s+[A-Z]\S*)*$
```

See another demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oVIsm5/1).

Comment: thanks !! for giving such a detailed explanation for the answer it cleared some of my doubts.
But it's not working for me and when i am adding this other validations are also not working.
can you please give some other way ??

Comment: @SnIpErReLoAdEd Can you give some examples where this is not working? You can update this regex link with your examples https://regex101.com/r/oVIsm5/1

Comment: yeah sure , should i add in the comments ?? oh thanks I'll update

Comment: @SnIpErReLoAdEd You can share the updated regex101 link here in the comments, or you can update the question with more example strings.

Comment: sure i'll update here.

Comment: @SnIpErReLoAdEd Which strings are not matching?

Comment: i added all my validations in separately didn't knew where else to update please look into it sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: all of them are not working if i am adding this, without this they are fine.

Comment: @SnIpErReLoAdEd So you mean that the example code in my answer is correct for all you example strings, but your code in the question is not working?

Comment: no, sorry if i am not able to express myself properly. I am saying when i am adding your regex all other regex which i have showed above are not working i.e they are not detecting only space , they are not detecting dot characters.

Comment: @SnIpErReLoAdEd Not this pattern does all of those in 1 pattern. That is what you want right?

Comment: no, i just want when i am entering a string it should check whether the first letter is capital or not and and it should be compatible with all my other validations.

Comment: it would be great if all of them can be combined in one otherwise separately would also work but all of them should be working.

Comment: @SnIpErReLoAdEd Checking that the string should not contain only dots or spaces can be done with `^[. ]*$` and then negate outcome of the match. If the string should start with an uppercase char, that is just `/^[A-Z]/`

Comment: Thank you !! for the help this answer cleared my doubts.